# How to avoid duplicating of WiFi networks in standard android WiFi list?

Tags: android, wifi

In my android app I connect to WiFi network. But, for example, if I connect to this network plenty of times, name of this network appears in standard android WiFi list plenty of times. How can I avoid this?

My code:

```
String networkSSID = "test"; 
String networkPass = "pass";
WifiConfiguration conf = new WifiConfiguration();
conf.SSID = "\"" + networkSSID + "\"";  
conf.preSharedKey = "\""+ networkPass +"\"";
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE); 
wifiManager.addNetwork(conf);
```

I'll add a screenshot as soon as possible

Comment: can you add some code and screenshots?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't call `addNetwork` if the Network already exists!
You can find that out by iterating over the `getConfiguredNetworks`from WifiManager.

If the Network already exists, just *connect* to it.

```
for (WifiConfiguration config : wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks()) {
   String newSSID = config.SSID;

   if (myNetworksSSID.equals(newSSID)) {
      wifiManager.disconnect();
      wifiManager.enableNetwork(config.networkId, true);
      wifiManager.reconnect();

     return;
   }
 }

 ...
 addNetwork(conf); //your old code
```

Answer (score 0):

Just scan the list for the wifi network name and skip it if exists. Just a possible solution without knowing your code. To do this you need a 2nd list to keep what you have discovered so far.

Comment: I guess you misunderstood a question. Network appears plenty of times in android standard WiFi list after connecting plenty of times, not in my app's list.